# How do I install a flatpak program so that it is avaiable system-wide?

Tags: linux, pop-os

It seems that, on my PopOS install at least, when installing from the PopShop, if installing from deb, the program is available to all users but not so for flatpak installs. How can I install a flatpak program in a way that it is available to multiple users?

When I try to run `flatpak install flathub net.xm1math.Texmaker` I get `Proceed with these changes to the user installation? [Y/n]:` so I guess the user install is the default?

Following the [flatpak docs](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-install) I tried `flatpak --system install flathub net.xm1math.Texmaker` but this gives me `error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’`. Why does this command not work?

**Edit:**

After adding the flathub ref and installing GIMP system wide, I now have a bunch of duplicate packages:

```
Name                           Application ID                             Version    Branch Installation
Discord                        com.discordapp.Discord                     0.0.12     stable user
Spotify                        com.spotify.Client                         1.1.42.622 stable user
Freedesktop Platform           org.freedesktop.Platform                   20.08.0    20.08  user
default                        org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                   19.08  system
default                        org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                   19.08  user
default                        org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                   20.08  user
nvidia-450-66                  org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-450-66             1.4    system
nvidia-450-66                  org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-450-66             1.4    user
openh264                       org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264          2.1.0      2.0    system
openh264                       org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264          2.1.0      2.0    user
Freedesktop SDK                org.freedesktop.Sdk                        20.08.0    20.08  user
GNU Image Manipulation Program org.gimp.GIMP                              2.10.20    stable system
Manual                         org.gimp.GIMP.Manual                                  2.10   system
Manual                         org.gimp.GIMP.Manual                                  2.10   user
GNOME Application Platform ve… org.gnome.Platform                                    3.36   system
GNOME Application Platform ve… org.gnome.Platform                                    3.36   user
Pop Gtk theme                  org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Pop-dark                            3.22   system
Pop Gtk theme                  org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Pop-dark                            3.22   user
KDE Application Platform       org.kde.Platform                                      5.15   user
QGnomePlatform                 org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform                  5.15   user
QtSNI                          org.kde.PlatformTheme.QtSNI                           5.15   user
QGnomePlatform-decoration      …ylandDecoration.QGnomePlatform-decoration            5.15   user
```

**Edit 2:**

Regarding the above, having multiple versions of large runtimes like the nvidia driver seems silly...

So I guess the "refs" are separate for each user, I was tempted to just delete my user one and see if PopShop will default to the other but don't want to mess things up too badly.

[popshop settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ihm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Comment: Cheers, that did do the trick, I guess PopShop doesn't pull installs from flathub? I'm not sure whether or not to use this though as I have many duplicate packages now and the PopShop doesn't detect the systemwide install (GIMP in this case, I'll edit my question with my `flatpak list` output).